# Beginner Using OOP in java how do I getAverage and getStandardDeviation()

Tags: java, standards, mean, deviation

Here's what I have so far from my code. this is an introductory course so we haven't covered more advanced topics yet. With what I gave so far I input number and press -1 but the program doesn't do anything.
**WE HAVEN'T COVERED ARRAYS YET.**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DataSet {
    private double value,count,sum, sumOfSquares, average;

    public DataSet(double value)
    {
        this.value=value;


    }
    public double getAverage(){
    int value=0;
    int count=0;
    double sum=0;
    while(value != -1){

        sum=sum+value;
    average=sum/count;

    }
        return average;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a numbers to get average and standard deviation: ");
        int value=input.nextInt();

        DataSet s= new DataSet(value);
        System.out.println(s.getAverage());
    }



}
```

Comment: see this  https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/master/mr/src/test/java/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/common/RunningAverageAndStdDevTest.java

Answer (score 0):

Try this below program. This class has only average method. You can add any number methods operating on values arraylist.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DataSet {

private List<Integer> values;

public DataSet(List<Integer> values) {
    this.values = values;
}

public double getAverage() {
    int sum = 0;
    double result = 0.0;
    for (int value : values) {
        sum = sum + value;
    }
    if (values.size() > 0) {
        result = sum / values.size();
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out
            .print("Enter a numbers to get average and standard deviation: ");
    int value = input.nextInt();
    while (value != -1) {
        values.add(value);
        value = input.nextInt();
    }
    DataSet s = new DataSet(values);
    System.out.println(s.getAverage());
}

}
```